# Can we use work equation to derive Ohm's law?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, work, electrical-resistance, voltage

Ohm's law states:
$$\textbf V=\textbf I\cdot\text R$$
where $\textbf V$ is voltage, the electric potential difference from a point to another (Electric potential is the potential energy of a positive charge, equivalent to the work needed to move the charge towards determined point since energy is the ability to do work and work is the change in energy, kinetic energy of the charge in this case.) $\textbf I$ is the current intensity or flow and $\text R$ is the resistance to current flow which depends on the length (the reason why resistors are drawn with zigzag shape to indicate increase in length), cross-sectional area and type of conducting material and temperature.

I thought about deriving this from the equation for work
$$\text W = \textbf F\cdot\textbf s$$
where $\text W$ is work and $\textbf F$ is the force applied to do the work and $\textbf s$ is the displacement caused by the work.

When I applied this to electricity, I had a problem with considering $\text W \equiv \textbf V$ because one is a scalar while the other is a vector, same with resistance which we can think of as the length of the conducting material ($\textbf s \not\equiv\text R$) and also current doesn't work because it is flow and not a force, but both are vectors.

Can these problems be ignored? Especially, can we think of current flow as the electric force for example?

Comment: What if I told you you could turn Ohm's Law around and write it as I = GV instead of V = IR? Now which is the "force"?

Comment: "Can current intensity be thought of as a force?" No.

Comment: $V$ is not a vector

Comment: @Buzz But $\text V$ is the product of a scalar (resistance) with a vector (intensity) right?

Comment: Current is a *scalar*; it is the surface integral of the (vector) current density $\mathbf J$ over a surface $S$: $I=\int_S \mathbf J\cdot d\mathbf S$. It is the amount of charge, per unit of time, flowing across the surface. The current density can be flowing in various directions across different parts of the surface.

Comment: In some cases, when a current is constrained to be in a wire, it can be considered to be a vector in the direction of the wire, but that is more of a special case. For a general understanding of current density and current through a surface, think about charges moving in space, not in a wire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When comparing electric current and mechanical motion the following are each other's counterpart:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| voltage | force |
| current | velocity |
| resistance | friction |

In mechanics the three central entities are:
-Acceleration
-Force
-Opposition to change of velocity: inertia.

The customary symbols:
$a$ acceleration, the second time derivative of position
$F$ Force
$m$ unit of inertia: mass

There is a counterpart of mechanical inertia: the self-[inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) of an inductor

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| voltage | force |
| current | velocity |
| self-inductance | inertia |

Discussion:

For simplicity we make all the electric conductors super-conducters, so we don't have to keep track of resistance.

The self-inductance of an inductor does not oppose current. The self-inductance opposes *change* of amount of current.

Current is amount of displacement of charge per unit of time. The opposition of an inductor to change is proportional to the *second time derivative* of displacement of charge.

The process of increasing the current through an inductor is analogous to acceleration of an object.

As a voltage is increasing the current through an inductor: the work done goes into increasing the magnetic field generated by the current running through the inductor

The energy associated with the current running through an inductor is analogous to kinetic energy.

That is the way to apply the concept of work done to electric current.

In mechanics: whenever friction is non-negligable it is accounted for, but friction is very much a circumstantial thing, it is accounted for on a case-by-case basis.

Whenever friction is draining energy from a system you can express that in the form of a friction force doing work, but in the case of friction there is no associated potential energy, so there is no way to treat it in a systematic way. Hence friction is treated on a case-by-case basis.

So:
Specific to your question: There is no way to obtain Ohm's law by way of the concept of work done; they are unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 4):

> Especially, can we think of current flow as the electric force for example?

Yes, but usually you go the other way: thinking of a force as a current. Mechanical systems are much more complicated than electrical systems. So it is sometimes useful to simplify a mechanical system and treat it as a circuit, but it is rarely useful to complicate a circuit and treat it as a mechanical system.

[Here](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Analogs/ElectricalMechanicalAnalogs.html#:%7E:text=To%20apply%20this%20analogy%2C%20every%20loop%20in%20the%20electrical%20circuit,source%20becomes%20a%20force%20generator) is a page on constructing analogous mechanical and electrical systems.

The “Mechanical Analog 1” treats forces as currents. So that is the one you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please link the work equation to Ohm's law using this analogous system, I can't. Are these the only possible consistent analogous systems? Considering other ones might fix the problem.

Comment: @user7777777 the work equation doesn’t link to ohms law. The mechanical power equation $P=Fv$ links to the electrical power equation $P=IV$. This actually is one consistency between both analogous systems. So I suspect it is important

Comment: @Dale if you want to link to $P=Fv$ then you should write it as $P=VI$ so that you get the ordering correct, even though ordering is meaningless in a scalar equation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent no, the ordering is correct. See the link in the answer. The OP is interested in the “mechanical analogy 1” where force is analogous to current. So the way I wrote it is according to that analogy.

Comment: @Dale, I see what you mean, but if you use analogy 1, then there is no sensible relationship between q, I and I dot that analogy 2 keeps intact. That is unsavoury.

Answer (score 3):

What Cleonis is saying is correct, but I want to emphasise a few things that he did not cover.

In Ohm's Law, $V=IR$, none of the quantities involved are actually vectors. Nonetheless, if you want to push the analogy with mechanics, you can consider the Lorentz force law
$$\tag1\vec F=q\vec E=-q\frac{\mathrm dV}{\vec{\mathrm dr}}$$
and see that the voltage difference $V$ is the one closest to forces.

Similarly, the current $I$ involves the flowing of charges, i.e. it has velocity of the charges inside, and thus is the one closest in analogy to velocities.

If you push this analogy, you might think that you are getting $F=mv$ which is not at all comparable to $F=ma$ that is the proper N2L. Actually, what is happening is that it is mechanics that is the awkward bunch of the lot. Most physics theories are closer to $F=mv$, and that is also what our intuitive understanding is closer to. It just so happens that our intuition are just completely wrong and needs to be corrected. What is *really* happening is that this is the parachute, terminal velocity problem:
\begin{align}
\tag2\text{N2L}:\qquad\sum\vec F&=\frac{\vec{\mathrm dp}}{\mathrm dt}\\
\tag3\rightarrow+\text{ve}:\qquad q\vec E-k\vec v&=m\vec a=\vec0
\end{align}
That is, what you are having is $F=kv$ balance between driving force and dissipation. This is actually what Ohm's Law is saying, and in late undergraduate physics you will learn to derive this fact.

---

Another reason why Ohm's Law cannot be formulated in terms of work, is because the energy equation is coming from
$$\tag4\frac{\mathrm dE}{\mathrm dt}=P=IV$$
and you use Ohm's Law to convert that to $P=\frac{V^2}R=I^2R$. i.e. the two concepts are necessarily orthogonal, or else you cannot do this.

---

The mechanics analogue that is between Dale and Cleonis's answer is really just that we realised that
$$\tag5L\dot I+RI+\frac1Cq=V_\text{ext}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad ma+\kappa v+kx=F_\text{ext}$$
That is, LRC circuit analysis is equivalent to a driven damped spring mechanics problem, and this equivalence is incredibly good.

Comment: I had actually not seen the abbreviation 'N2L' before, I had to google it. Incidentally, I would prefer to refer to it as 'the Force-Acceleration Principle', or 'the Principle of Inertia'. I believe that it should have a standalone name, rather than being referred to as part of an enumeration. (Enumeration lacks flexibility; physicists enumerated first, second, and third law of thermodynamics, and then the realization came there was a principle logically preceding it, which was squeezed in by naming it 'the zeroth law'.) So yeah, I avoid using the enumerating name.

Comment: @Cleonis that is the name that history has chosen for us. It is not going to be subjected to your problem because the Principia is a completed piece of work and everybody understands what N1L N2L N3L individually means. However, I am also in favour of progress, but that would mean to completely stop teaching mechanics from the PoV of forces, a view that Hertz also proposed. For example, nowhere else in physics do we have N3L style silliness, which is only coming about because forces is just the wrong way to look at mechanics. `Principle of Inertia' is more N1L.

Comment: My take: by now we know which of the conceptions laid out in the Principia have stood the test of time, and which haven't. Example: N3L is no longer taught in that form; mechanics education has shifted to demonstrating conservation of the total momentum of a set of objects that are exchanging momentum. Be it as it may; these two comments of mine to your answer are unrelated to the original question; I won't persue further.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to think of $V$ as a force acting on an amount of charge, say $q$, so that the work done *by* $V$ as it moves $q$ over a time interval $t$ is $w=Vq$. Then the work done per unit time is $p=V\frac{q}{t}$ but the current is just the amount of charge moved per unit time, $I=\frac{q}{t}$, therefore the work rate, ie. power, is $p=VI$.

Also, note that the voltage $V$ is not a vector, the voltage per unit length, that is electric field intensity along the direction of said length is a vector.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why voltage is not a vector? Because voltage is the product of a scalar  (resistance) and a vector (intensity) so it has to be a vector, otherwise intensity has to be a scalar or resistance has to be a vector, as far as I understand. Also your answer considers $\textbf V$ as a force which is a vector.

Comment: take three points, $A,B,C$; there are three voltages among them $V_{AB},V_{BC},V_{AC}$. It does not matter what how the points are in space relative to each other, voltages always satisfy this equation: $V_{AB}+V_{BC}=V_{AC}$. These are numbers, scalars not vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a voltage of 5V between two points 3 meters away:

The force each charge will feel at each point along the line:
E * Q = (5V / 3) * Q (Newtons)

Work = (E * Q * distance) = (5/3) * Q * 3 = 5 * Q (Newton * meters)

Now by the looks of it the work can be anything: if you move more charge by 3 meters, you get more work done by the electric field:

Work (moving 1 C by 3 meters) = 5 J
Work (moving 2 C by 3 meters) = 10 J

**But even here, notice that the work per 1 C is always 5 J.**

Then the resistance comes in:
**the amount of energy consumed by the resistance from each charge moving across it depends on how much current is moving through the resistance overall.**

If the resistance is 2.5 Ohms, to move 1 C across it in 1 sec (1 A) costs 2.5 J per Columb.

If you move 3 C in 1 sec, it will cost 7.5 J from each of the 3 Columbs separately (7.5 J for each of the 3, and 22.5 J overall).

Each of these can't work because each 1 C of charge either pays more or less energy than it has (5 J).

But if you move 2 C across it in 1 sec (2 A) it costs 5 J per each Coloumb. And each Columb has 5 J from the voltage gap of 5 V. Thus the work the electric field puts in equals to the amount of work consumed by the resistance in the second in question.